# Angular 8 custom library routing in main application

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, nexus, angular-library

I want to create a library with modules, components, services, json & Routes configurations in order to be able to use it in several applications, then i will export it via public-api.ts
and publish (library) to NPM private repository.

**Question 1**: This library is installed in main runnable angular applications wherever required, but routing's configured in library are not working from runnable app's. How do we achieve routing configured in library to work in runnable app's.

**Question 2**: How to invoke a method defined in angular library module from Angular runnable app using dynamic import?

```
like: import('@myorg/lib-name')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think having any kind of routing in a reusable library is a bad idea. Your application should control its routes.

Comment: How to dynamically control routing from my runnable applications(where the routing config is common for all the runnable app's). @AdamDunkerley